# Microsoft Graph API not exposing certain properties

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I've been looking into using the Graph API from Microsoft to monitor a few online Exchange inboxes.

I was reading their documentation [here for Outlook Messages](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message) but I'm looking for `conversationTopic`. I know this is exposed in the normal Outlook Object Model; but I don't see it exposed in their documentation.

Has MS exposed this property in their API?

Answer (score 1):

**Info as of 9/15/2016**

The **conversationThread** property has only been exposed in group conversations. It hasn't been exposed in a first class manner for a user's messages. This has been exposed on the [beta](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata) endpoint via [extended properties](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/extended-properties-overview.htm) . You'll want to use the [PidTagConversationTopic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178547(v=exchg.80).aspx) property.

Here's an example call to get this property (you'll just need to add your message id):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages('YOURMESSAGEID')?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%200x0070')`

Here it is for easier reading (no URL encoding):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages('YOURMESSAGEID')?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x0070')`

Comment: @Michael...thanks for the info. I'll try this end-point soon and get back to you.

Comment: I'm attempting to use the endpoint but where am I supposed to retrieve the `MessageId` ?

Comment: Call GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages, that will return a page of 10 messages. If you need to find a specific message, you'll want to add an OData query parameter.

Comment: I'm calling this but I keep getting a `404 Not Found`. What could be the issue? This is the line: `"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages('AAMkADlmZmRlNjIxLTllZjAtNDQ3Ny05ZjkxLWIyMDExY2Q1NzJmNABGAAAAAACbQlquq3CSTJtU-xG6W-SGBwB2Xcyp1Gg9SK-FIEacP39NAAAAAAENAAB2Xcyp1Gg9SKFIEacP39NAAKTtGNgAAA=')?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x0070')"`

Comment: Even if I try with the following I'm getting the `404`. `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages('AAMkADlmZmRlNjIxLTllZjAtNDQ3Ny05ZjkxLWIyMDExY2Q1NzJmNABGAAAAAACbQlquq3CSTJtU-xG6W-SGBwB2Xcyp1Gg9SK-FIEacP39NAAAAAAENAAB2Xcyp1Gg9SK-FIEacP39NAAKTtGNgAAA=')?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%200x0070')`

Comment: If you try ```https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages('AAMkADlmZmRlNj‌​IxLTllZjAtNDQ3Ny05Zj‌​kxLWIyMDExY2Q1NzJmNA‌​BGAAAAAACbQlquq3CSTJ‌​tU-xG6W-SGBwB2Xcyp1G‌​g9SK-FIEacP39NAAAAAA‌​ENAAB2Xcyp1Gg9SK-FIE‌​acP39NAAKTtGNgAAA=')‌```, does it find the message? It seems like that specific message no longer exists, or that you're targeting a different mailbox than expected..

Comment: @Michael..I'll try that today. Couldn't get a chance yesterday. I'll update you soon.